# Regular Expression Validation with Default Text?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have a watermark on my text box. I have put in required field validator and regex validator on the text box. Now the problem is I want that when watermark is present on the text box and user clicks the button, then user should see required message instead of error message.

But since there is some text in the text box, thus regex validator also gets fired. 
Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code. Its working fine.

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomerName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RrequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="Please customer name" ControlToValidate="txtCustomerName" ForeColor="Red"
    Display="Dynamic">
   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit Form" />
    <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="wMarkExtndr"
    TargetControlID="txtCustomerName" WatermarkText="Enter customer name"
    runat="server">
    </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not seeing TextBoxWatermarkExtender in my ajax controls, do I need to refer some DLL ?

Comment: <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

Comment: please register ajax control toolkit.

Comment: download latest release of AJAXControlToolkit at (http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/76976)